# Как считывать из потока?

Tags: c#, uwp

Мне надо записывать данные в поток, затем считывать эти данные из потока. В C# я могу использовать `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` (и ему подобные) или `MemoryStream`. Но, к моему сожалению, считывание не удаляет эти данные из потока. Так вот вопрос: как считывать байты и удалять их из потока? И какой именно поток мне создавать?

Важная информация: я записываю и считываю данные по частям, т.е. я не могу просто полностью очистить поток. Не очищать поток по мере считывания тоже не могу, поскольку тогда приложение слишком сильно занимает ЦП.

Comment: Простейший циклический буфер с указателями чтения и записи - ровно то, что вам нужно. Главное размер подобрать правильный.

Comment: Вам нужен не поток, такой вид впреобразований называется **стек** или **очередь** , возможно pipe (если между разними thread). Очереди бывают **lifo** и **fifo** вам нужна последняя. Также в простейших случаях можно обойтись циклическим буфером.

Comment: Есть решение System.Collections.Queue  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx тут методы Enqueue и Dequeue. Также посмотрите System.Collections.Stack

Comment: @nick_n_a Есть дефолтный Stack<T>, у которого есть и Pop(), и Push(). Возвращает первый элемент списка(добавленный раньше всех), что в общем то мне и надо. Но нормально ли этот stack работает? Мне нужно брать данные каждые 10-40 мс.

Comment: @nick_n_a Да, спасибо. Сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: Конечно решение с циклическим буфером удет работать быстрее чем эти библиотечные решения. Потом, если у вас обьекты и не хотите морочится с буфером, добавьте поле с ссылкой на "следующий" обьект, и сделайте "связанные" цепные обьекты. Типа MyObject {  MyObject next;  }; Я за циклический буфер.

Comment: @nick_n_a Ну, Queue меня пока устраивает. Спасибо вам.

Comment: @nick_n_a Queue<T> и построена на циклическом буфере, там только при увеличении емкости производительность проседает, но этот момент тоже неплохо оптимизирован. Можете сами посмотреть http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs,aa3beab99b2e0db2